# How to make a warning to user when 10 secs. to refresh setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am using setInterval to refresh a content of graph in page. How to make a show an alert to user when setinterval is about to refresh that 'the content will be refreshed'.

For example my interval is using 300 secs and I want to show an alert after 290 seconds have passed that 'The content will be refreshed after 10 secs. Do you want to refresh the graph' for each interval. How to do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: The function which is triggered by `setInterval` actually 1) displays the alert and 2) sets a *timeout* to trigger to actual refresh 10 seconds later...!?

Comment: It would be easier to help if we would see the code, edit your question with more information.

Comment: if you show the alert in between then your code execution will be halted till the time user presses OK button of alert.

Comment: Seeing some code would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set you interval to 290000ms, and then it will show an alert, and then you use setTimeout to update your page after 10 seconds, like so:

```js
  setInterval(function() {
    alert("10 seconds to update")
    setTimeout(function() {
         //REFRESH PAGE
     },5000);
  }, 10000);
```

Comment: In such case timeout will be invoked every 10 seconds. By the way timeout time is set to 5000, why?

Comment: @Tamango - Correct? This is just an example to show how it works, so you don't have to wait 290 seconds to see it working. If he chooses to use this, he should do like I wrote on top, change the interval from 10000 to 290000.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
var interval;
var secondsPassed = 0;
function refreshWithMessage() {
  interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(secondsPassed == 290) {
       //showMessage with options
    }
    if(secondsPassed == 300) {
       clearInterval(interval);
       //do what you need here (refresh page?)
    }
    secondsPassed++;
  }, 1000)
}
```

If you need to let user cancel the interval - you should just clear interval and then reset seconds variable to 0.

Answer (score 1):

On your page loading you can put your 290 secs refresh

```
 setInterval(function(){ 
     showDialogBox("do you want to refresh");
 }, 290000);
```

and then add a action on the confirm button that will be delayed the last 10sec

```
 confirmButtonOnClick(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
       refresh();
    }, 10000);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, I prefer to use `setTimeout` over `setInterval` as it gives better control.

So I set two timers -- one for the warning and then another for the timeout itself, then I restart the two timers.

```js
const timeoutWarning = 1800;
const timeoutDone = 2000;

function showWarning() {
  console.log('About to time out...');
}

function doTimeout() {
  console.log('Timeout reached');
  setWarnings();
}

function setWarnings() {
  setTimeout(showWarning, timeoutWarning);
  setTimeout(doTimeout, timeoutDone);
}

setWarnings();
```

Comment: Thank you this is what exactly i asked